Limiting Tasks in MS Project 2016
BLUF: I only want the resource to have a max of 2 events per day in autoschedule mode.
I am building an automatic flight schedule, where i have a template that is the student syllabus, with a single milestone at then end which is the winging. Each student will be an individual project and a resource. So in student X's project, I put in the winging date and its predecessor as the prior event ##FF. I assign the student then as the resource (units 100%). Their work day is 18 hours, but can only be scheduled for 22% of it or 4 hours (max units). When I level though, it still gives them 8 events a day where sims are 1.5 hours and flights are 2 hours. How can I limit it to max 2 events per day?
